# Combine values of a list of data that are almost equal

Tags: java, list, merge, java-stream

so i asked before but it seems i wasnt clear enough of what im talking about, so im trying to make it clearer now:
what im trying to do is prepare data for an import. the data i get is human made an not very efficient, so im removing unnecessary entrys and try to combine the data as much as possible.

its for something like a configurator. the data i get looks something like this:

123 : 45 : AB = 12
This means: if Option 1 is 1 OR 2 OR 3 and Option 2 is 4 OR 5 and Option 3 is A OR B the result will be 1 AND 2

i created a class thats something like this:

```
Class Options{
    String opt1;
    String opt2;
    String opt3;
    String optResult;

    //and some other stuff

    boolean hasSameOptions(Options o){
        return opt1.equals(o.opt1) && opt2.equals(o.opt2) && opt3.equals(o.opt3);
    }

    public void AddOptions(String options) {
        for (String s : options.split("")) {
            if (!optResult.contains(s)) {
                optResult = optResult + s;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

now, the data is repetitive and can be combined. Like:

```
12 : 45 : AB = 12
12 : 45 : AB = 3
12 : 45 : AB = 4
```

This would mean actually mean: 12 : 45 : AB = 1234

So, what i do is break the Strings apart to get only single values with the result, for example:

```
1 : 4 : A = 12
1 : 4 : B = 12
1 : 5 : A = 12 
//and so on.
```

I make a list of all these Values and then try to Combine them again to get more efficient List.

The first step i do is get all Objects who have the same Options but different Results and combine the results. that happens like this:

```
public static List<Options> cleanList(List<Options> oldList) {

    List<Options> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Options item : oldList) {
        Options temp = findEqualOptions(newList, item);
        if (temp != null)
            temp.AddOptions(item.optResult);
        else
            newList.add(item);
    }

    return newList;
}

public static <T> T findByProperty(Collection<T> col, Predicate<T> filter) {
    return col.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(filter).findFirst().orElse(null);
}

public static Options findEqualOptions(List<Options> list, Options opt) {
    return findByProperty(list, d -> d.hasSameOptions(opt));
}
```

After that, i try to compress the list even more, by combining elements who have only ONE different value. For example:

```
1 : 2 : A = 12
1 : 3 : A = 12 
 -> 1 : 23 : A = 12
```

i do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
        Option o1 = list.get(i);
        Option o2 = list.get(j);
        int diff1 = 0;
        int diff2 = 0;
        int diff3 = 0;
        int diff4 = 0;


        if(!o1.opt1.equals(o2.opt1))
            diff1 = 1;
        if(!o1.opt2.equals(o2.opt2))
            diff2 = 1;

        //and so on

        if((diff1+diff2+diff3+diff4)>1)
            continue;

        if(diff1 == 1)
            o1.opt1 = o1.opt1 + o2.opt1;

        //and so on...


        list.remove(j--);


    }
}
```

i do this until there are no more changes. It works well, but slowly. especially the method cleanList().
does anybody have any idea how to make it better? i tried to use a stream to get the whole list of equals options directly like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> findByMultipleValue(Collection<T> col, Predicate<T> filter) {
    return col.stream().filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static List<Options> getEqualOptionsList(List<Options> optList, Options opt){
    return findByMultipleValue(optList, o -> o.hasSameOptions(opt));
}
```

but that made it A LOT slower.

PS. : its not the complete code, just an example of what im trying to do. I hope it is more understandable this time :)

Comment: Maybe express the left side of each "equation" as a string, pretty much like it's written, and store it in a hash, where the value in the hash is the combined possible results. So you'd read the first one, take the string made from the LHS, discover it's not in your hash, so add it. The next time you hit the same LHS, instead of adding you would grab the existing value and append the new one. Hash lookups are very fast, so you'll get O(n) on that part.

Comment: @JosephLarson thanks for the tipp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably not the most elegant or optimal solution but here is already a quick approach that give the result based on your description. It use the HashMap as proposed in the comment of @Joseph Larson

I went for a set of char to ensure values are not duplicate in it but feel free to adapt :)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

class Scratch {
    public static class Option{
        String opt1;
        String opt2;
        String opt3;
        String optResult;

        public Option(String opt1, String opt2, String opt3, String optResult) {
            this.opt1 = opt1;
            this.opt2 = opt2;
            this.opt3 = opt3;
            this.optResult = optResult;
        }

        public static String merge(String a, String b){
            StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
            Set<Character> result = new HashSet<>();
            for(char c : a.toCharArray()){
                result.add(c);
            }
            for(char c : b.toCharArray()){
                result.add(c);
            }
            for(char c : result){
                value.append(c);
            }
            return value.toString();
        }

        public Option(Option a, Option b) {
            this(merge(a.opt1, b.opt1), merge(a.opt2, b.opt2), merge(a.opt3, b.opt3), merge(a.optResult, b.optResult));
        }

        String getKey(){
            return String.join(":", opt1, opt2, opt3);
        }

        int distance(Option option){
            int diff1 = this.opt1.equals(option.opt1)?0:1;
            int diff2 = this.opt2.equals(option.opt2)?0:1;
            int diff3 = this.opt3.equals(option.opt3)?0:1;
            int diff4 = this.optResult.equals(option.optResult)?0:1;
            return diff1 + diff2 + diff3 + diff4;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return getKey();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Option[] data = new Option[]{
                new Option("12", "45", "AB", "12"),
                new Option("12", "45", "AB", "3"),
                new Option("12", "45", "AB", "4"),
                new Option("12", "45", "AC", "1"),
                new Option("12", "45", "AC", "12"),
                new Option("3", "45", "AC", "13"),
                new Option("12", "45", "AD", "12"),
        };

        mergeExact(data);
        mergeClose(data, 1);
    }

    private static void mergeClose(Scratch.Option[] data, int distance){
        Map<Option, Set<Character>> buffer = new HashMap<>();
        for(Option option : data) {
            boolean found = false;
            Option toDelete = null;
            for(Map.Entry<Option, Set<Character>> entry : buffer.entrySet()){
                if(option.distance(entry.getKey()) <= distance){
                    Option merged = new Option(entry.getKey(), option);
                    for(char c : option.optResult.toCharArray()){
                        entry.getValue().add(c);
                    }
                    buffer.put(merged, entry.getValue());
                    toDelete = entry.getKey();
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found) {
                buffer.remove(toDelete);
            }else{
                Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
                for(char c : option.optResult.toCharArray()){
                    set.add(c);
                }
                buffer.put(option, set);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("merge with distance of %d:: %s", distance, buffer));

    }

    private static void mergeExact(Scratch.Option[] data) {
        Map<String, Set<Character>> buffer = new HashMap<>();
        for(Option option : data){
            Set<Character> item = buffer.computeIfAbsent(option.getKey(), k -> new HashSet<>());
            for(char c : option.optResult.toCharArray()){
                item.add(c);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("exact merge:: "+buffer);
    }


}
```

output is

```
exact merge:: {3:45:AC=[1, 3], 12:45:AD=[1, 2], 12:45:AC=[1, 2], 12:45:AB=[1, 2, 3, 4]}
merge with distance of 1:: {12:45:AB=[1, 2, 3, 4], 3:45:AC=[1, 3], 12:45:ACD=[1, 2]}
```

EDIT: missed a part of the question, updating to add the merge when difference is close. This part is probably even worst that the first one in terms of optimisation but it's a working bases :)

Comment: you missed the part where the String on the left side is broken down to the core elements to make single statements, i edided my post because i think it wasnt very good to see. i used you solution for "just" the cleanList method and its a hell of a lot faster, still need to work a little on my implementation but thanks a lot!